# Index positioning to left with respect to main content using Asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am creating an Index document using Asciidoctor which enlists all my subsequent collection of documents. The output that is generated lists the indexes on top of the main content at the center of the page.

I visited
[Asciidoctor User Manual](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#left-or-right-column-layout) and tried using `:toc: left` to move the index to the left, but the said thing didn't happen. It still renders the index at the top of the main content and not to the left of the main content.

How should I move further?

Help much appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `toc: left` was overridden by the Gradle script which was used to build it. Everytime the value at compilation was overridden to `toc: ''` to an empty string, which by default renders it in the center of the page. Hence it wasn't working.

**Solution:**
Removed the dependency, and now it works. :)